# Pandas Dataframe simple Stats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I want to find the average number of points scored by the team per game in each season.

Is there a easy way to consider both the case when the team won `Wscore` and when the team lost `Lscore`?

```
    Season  Daynum  Wteam   Wscore  Lteam   Lscore  Wloc    Numot
0   1985    20     1228     81      1328       64     N      0
1   1985    25     1106     77      1354       70     H      0
```

`season` - this is the year of the associated entry in seasons.csv (the year in which the final tournament occurs)

`daynum` - this integer always ranges from 0 to 132, and tells you what day the game was played on. It represents an offset from the `dayzero` date in the `seasons.csv` file. For example, the first game in the file was daynum=20. Combined with the fact from the `season.csv` file that day zero was 10/29/1984, that means the first game was played 20 days later, or 11/18/1984. There are no teams that ever played more than one game on a given date, so you can use this fact if you need a unique key. In order to accomplish this uniqueness, we had to adjust one game's date. In March 2008, the SEC postseason tournament had to reschedule one game (Georgia-Kentucky) to a subsequent day, so Georgia had to actually play two games on the same day. In order to enforce this uniqueness, we moved the game date for the Georgia-Kentucky game back to its original date.

`wteam` - this identifies the id number of the team that won the game, as listed in the `teams.csv` file. No matter whether the game was won by the home team or visiting team, `wteam` always identifies the winning team.

`wscore` - this identifies the number of points scored by the winning team.

`lteam` - this identifies the id number of the team that lost the game.

`lscore` - this identifies the number of points scored by the losing team.

`numot` - this indicates the number of overtime periods in the game, an integer 0 or higher.

`wloc` - this identifies the `location` of the winning team. If the winning team was the home team, this value will be `H`. If the winning team was the visiting team, this value will be `A`. If it was played on a neutral court, then this value will be `N`. Sometimes it is unclear whether the site should be considered neutral, since it is near one team's home court, or even on their court during a tournament, but for this determination we have simply used the Kenneth Massey data in its current state, where the `@` sign is either listed with the winning team, the losing team, or neither team.

Comment: Could you update the dataframe example? I cannot understand what that line of numbers is for.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, what issues are you facing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then try to improve your question by editing it, focusing on a specific problem and giving details about it (code, configuration, error messages, exact problem your are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to go about doing this.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['Season','Daynum','Wteam','Wscore','Lteam','Lscore','Wloc','Numot']
colx = ['Season','Daynum','Team', 'Score']
dt   = [[1985, 20, 1228, 81, 1328, 64, 'N', 0],
        [1985, 20, 1354, 77, 1228, 70, 'H', 0],
        [1985, 25, 1106, 77, 1354, 70, 'H', 0],
        [1985, 25, 1328, 82, 1106, 78, 'N', 0],
        [1985, 21, 1106, 77, 1228, 65, 'N', 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dt,columns=cols)

#take the first 4 columns into d1. Keep only Season, Wteam, Wscore
#rename Wteam and Wscore as Team and Score
d1 = df.iloc[:,:4]
d1 = d1.rename(columns={'Wteam': 'Team', 'Wscore': 'Score'})
d1 = d1.drop(columns = ['Daynum'])

#take the first 4 columns into d1. Keep only Season, Lteam, Lscore
#rename Lteam and Lscore as Team and Score
d2 = df.iloc[:,:6]
d2 = d2.drop(columns =['Daynum','Wteam','Wscore'])
d2 = d2.rename(columns={'Lteam': 'Team', 'Lscore': 'Score'})

#Now you have two dataframes that have common name but subsets of original dataframe
d3 = pd.concat([d1,d2])

#Group by Season and Team to get the average Score for each team by each Season
print(d3 = d3.groupby(['Season','Team']).mean())

#To show you the breakup of each set, I am printing all the dataframes
print(df)
print(d1)
print(d2)
print(d3)
```

**DataFrame of Average Score by Season and Team**

```
                 Score
Season Team           
1985   1106  77.333333
       1228  72.000000
       1328  73.000000
       1354  73.500000
```

**Original Dataframe:**

```
   Season  Daynum  Wteam  Wscore  Lteam  Lscore Wloc  Numot
0    1985      20   1228      81   1328      64    N      0
1    1985      20   1354      77   1228      70    H      0
2    1985      25   1106      77   1354      70    H      0
3    1985      25   1328      82   1106      78    N      0
4    1985      21   1106      77   1228      65    N      0
```

**DataFrame with only list of Win Teams**

```
   Season  Team  Score
0    1985  1228     81
1    1985  1354     77
2    1985  1106     77
3    1985  1328     82
4    1985  1106     77
```

**DataFrame with only list of Loss Teams**

```
   Season  Team  Score
0    1985  1328     64
1    1985  1228     70
2    1985  1354     70
3    1985  1106     78
4    1985  1228     65
```

**Merged DataFrame with list of both Win & Loss Teams**

This will be the list you need to group by and calculate the average

```
   Season  Team  Score
0    1985  1228     81
1    1985  1354     77
2    1985  1106     77
3    1985  1328     82
4    1985  1106     77
0    1985  1328     64
1    1985  1228     70
2    1985  1354     70
3    1985  1106     78
4    1985  1228     65
```